# Electrostatics and field lines

Tags: electrostatics, electric-fields, charge

As we know positive charge's field lines terminate at infinity and negative charges originate at infinity, so can we say that positive charge becomes negative at infinity and vice versa?

Answer (score 1):

'As we know positive charge's field lines terminate at infinity and negative charges originate at infinity'

The premise is not necessarily correct

Charge Reversal is not a property of the virtue of Electric Fields. Please Edit your question as it sounds strange to say the least.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, what we usually tell is electric field originates from a positive charge and ends on a negative charge. This time you placed a positive charge and there is no negative charge anywhere and now you ask, ''where this field ends? , there is no negative charge nearby''.
Then I will tell it will travel a large distance in search of a negative charge and eventually and painfully it dies out. This is what we call electric field lines ends at infinity. Similarly for negative charge also. This does not have anything to do with charge reversal.